# Best approach to search bars and table views in ios

Tags: ios, ios8, uisearchbar, ios9, uisearchcontroller

What is best practice as of today:

```
1. Use a UISearchController to handle searching.
or
2. Create a view controller that has a UISearchBar and scope bar with a UITableView as the results.
or
3. Or some other way.
```

Thanks.

Comment: handle option no 1 and option 2 is fine for your concept

Comment: would need the example for this concept

Comment: I think the best approach I've found his here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html Thanks for commenting

Comment: please ref this link also http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/, this link is old but conecpt is good

Answer (score 0):

you can go with option 1 if you need to run your app on ios8 or above. Since ios7 does not support uisearchcontroller so we need to use uisearchbar with ios7.